# How can I override the createPages query from a Gatsby theme?

Tags: gatsby

I'm using the Gatsby theme blog. I installed it in a new site [as documented here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-theme-blog/) and everything works. I want to change the query for the main posts index. I see it in the theme's gatsby-node. How do I override it in my site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [shadowing](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/theme-api/#shadowing) to replace the `gatsby-node.js` file. That means that you place your own gatsby-node.js file corresponding to the path of the theme gatsby-node.js file.

From the docs: `Until we build tooling to support automatically handling shadowing, you will have to manually locate paths in a theme and create the correct shadowing paths in your site.`

`gatsby-node.js` is a special file in the Gatsby build process. I don't know if "just replacing" is possible like that. If it does not work as easy as described in the docs I recommend to delete the main post index query in the theme and replacing it there with your own.